# Native sound library on Android that can actually change pitch?

Tags: android, c++, audio, android-ndk, opensl

I'm confused as to how to set pitch natively on Android.  I tried altering the native-sound sample from the NDK which uses OpenSL ES, but I get a SL_RESULT_FEATURE_UNSUPPORTED for pretty much anything related to pitch upon requesting the interface.  Interfaces tried: SL_IID_PITCH, SL_IID_RATEPITCH, SL_3DDOPPLER

```
// create audio player
const SLInterfaceID ids[3] = { SL_IID_BUFFERQUEUE, SL_IID_PITCH, SL_IID_VOLUME};
const SLboolean req[3] = {SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE, SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE, SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE};
result = (*engineEngine)->CreateAudioPlayer(engineEngine, &bqPlayerObject, &audioSrc, &audioSnk,
        3, ids, req);
assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
```

result is always SL_RESULT_UNSUPPORTED

My target is android-19.  I tried many others as well to no avail.  Am I doing something wrong?  Is there an alternative that doesn't require using Java?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android has a minimal implementation of OpenSL, and none of those interfaces are supported. You can find a description of what is supported (and what has been added) in the NDK docs, or [here](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/ndk/docs/opensles/index.html) - the link is the exact same as the documentation from the NDK.

Unfortunately, there is no easy alternative besides writing your own algorithm to alter the PCM data.

Answer (score 0):

The Synthesis ToolKit (STK) has a pitch shift effect that may work for you.
https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/

As Dave pointed out, there is no native solution. At present, I would say Android is not the place to look for good native audio support.